# Parsing a double pipe delimited file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, parsing

Need to parse a data file delimited by **||** and the data is as follows

```
Customer No||Company Code||Name||Address||Telephone||Fax||Email||Term of Payment||Block||Created On||Last Changed On
000111111||A75||My Company||My Address||01-11111111||01- 11111111||test@test.com||A075||||1.11.2019||11.11.2019
```

Using csv module, and the code that does parsing is

`csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='||')`

and getting following error while executing

`TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string`

I'm using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csv [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter) says

> A one-character string used to separate fields. It defaults to ','.

This is a hard constraint. One of the hacks that I can think of is to do some modification to the content string before being read by `csv.reader`. You can use `replace('||', '|')` method on each line of the input file before giving it as an argument to `csv.reader`.

```
input_file  = open('test.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader((line.replace('||', '|') for line in input_file), delimiter='|')
```

Comment: That seems dangerous, since it would make a field separator out of any single `|` which happened to be present in a field. It would at least be useful to first check whether such a condition exists.

Comment: Agree with you @rici, but again this was one of the hacks that may or may not work depending on the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using the pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', sep='\|\|', 
              engine='python', header=None)
print(df)
```